# Adding Circles dynamically with array or arrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, geometry

i'm trying to add circles dynamically in a for-loop. At the moment it looks like this:

```
    public static void addCircle(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
    circlesOnTheField++;
    //for(int k = 0; k < circles.size(); k++) {
        //Random r = new Random();
        //int randomX = r.nextInt();
        //int randomY = r.nextInt();
        //Hier muss noch CollisionDetection nachgefü+gt werden
        //c1 = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 33);
        //circles.add(c1);
        //canvas.drawCircle(c1.getX(), c1.getY(), c1.getR(), p1);
    }
}
```

My arrays are these:

```
    //private static ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    //private static String[] circleNames = {"c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10","c11","c12","c13","c14","c15","c16","c17","c18","c19","c20"};
    private static Circle[] circles = new Circle[50];
    static Circle viking, testoppo, c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20;
```

I thought, it should work when i do it like this (within the for-loop):

```
Circle circleNames[k] = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 33);
```

But it does not work!

How can i get it done without using this fix "c1"?

Thank you guys!

EDIT:
I changed the "addCircle" method to only increment a variable "circlesOnTheField". I put the circle initialization (circle = new Circle etc.) into the constructor of Drawing. And in the "onDraw()" method, i want to draw the circle if my "circlesOnTheField" is more than 0. There must be something i overlook!
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

```
public Drawing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;

        viking = new Circle(160,160, 33, "viking");
        testoppo = new Circle (32, 150, 33, "testoppo");

        for(int k = 0; k < circles.length; k++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int randomX = r.nextInt();
            int randomY = r.nextInt();
            //Hier muss noch CollisionDetection nachgefü+gt werden
            circles[k] = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 33, "Circle"+k);
        }

        pMe.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        p1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        p2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        p3.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    protected void onDraw (android.graphics.Canvas canvas){

    lerpX = (circleCenterX - viking.getX()) * (time / frames) + viking.getX();
    lerpY = (circleCenterY - viking.getY()) * (time / frames) + viking.getY();

    canvas.drawCircle(lerpX, lerpY, viking.getR(), pMe);
    canvas.drawCircle(testoppo.getX(), testoppo.getY(), testoppo.getR(), p1);

    if(circlesOnTheField>0)
    {
    canvas.drawCircle(circles[0].getX(), circles[0].getY(), circles[0].getR(), p1);
    }
    viking.setX(lerpX);
    viking.setY(lerpY);
}
```

EDIT 2:
Fixed it by setting a value to `r.nextInt(255);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method, as is, will never create additional circles if `circles` is empty when the program starts (`circles.size()` will return 0). Also, `Circle circleNames[k] = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 33);` will throw an error - bad syntax. I think, instead, you should just have the following method for adding in a circle:

```
public static void addCircle(/*android.graphics.Canvas canvas*/) {
        //circlesOnTheField++; this variable is wasteful; you can retreive this value by calling circles.size()
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomX = r.nextInt();
        int randomY = r.nextInt();
        c1 = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 33);
        circles.add(c1);
        //canvas.drawCircle(c1.getX(), c1.getY(), c1.getR(), p1);
    }
}
```

You shouldn't be drawing the circle to the Canvas during this method; that job is not its resposibility. That code should go into a `drawCircles()` method. As a result of that, you don't need `android.graphics.Canvas canvas` as a parameter anymore.

Comment: Jepp ok thanks, and how can I replace the "c1" ? I would like to call "addCircle()" each time I want to have a new circle and maybe there is a way to always take a new circlename too?

Comment: Where do you set the circle's name? Is there a field `name` in the `Circle` class? @Jolle

Comment: Nope but this is a good idea ;) ! I thought I could work with the string array "cardNames"...

Comment: Yup, then after you declare `c1` you could simply do this: `c1.setName("Circle " + (circles.size() + 1));` @Jolle

Comment: Thanks! But I still stuck with the problem of "c1". Because, I add circles with a timer every 10 seconds. But with this "c1" it will always be the same circle, right? I need a way to get it dynamically.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking @Jolle

Comment: Ok, sorry, i try to get more clearer! I want to add a new circle every 10 seconds with a timer by calling the method `addCircle`. Therefore I need to get away from `c1 = new Circle()` and rather use something like `circle[k] = new Circle()`.